# http.request() method not working with urls having subdomains

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to post some data like this

```
var options={hostname:'www.sub.domain.com',path:'post.php?'+qs.stringify(postData), method:'GET '};
```

and then calling this object with http.request(). It throws this error

```
   events.js:71
        throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                       ^
Error: Parse Error
    at Socket.socketOnData (http.js:1485:20)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:404:27)
```

What may be the issue?

Comment: path should start with /  path:'/post.php?'...

Comment: Don't send post data as query parameters in a POST request but as the actual request body.

Comment: no its again the same. with GET method as well as /post.php as path

Comment: see my question edited...

Comment: Did you ever get this working?  I'm having the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

Use host instead hostname in "option" object. Try as follows,

```
var options = {
    host : 'www.sub.domain.com',
    path:'/post.php?'+qs.stringify(postData),
    method : 'GET'
  };
```